# Use of the word "collate"

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

I just want to know if my sentence is correct using the word "collated".

> Please see attached file for our Question bank collated during our meetings.

Is the message of the sentence correct?

If not, could you provide me with a better sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please see **the** attached file for our Question bank **which we** collated during our meetings.

Firstly, I would add a *the*, because you are referring to a specific attachment.

Secondly, I would add *which we*, so you have a proper subject. *Collated* is now used as an adjective, but it seems to be referring to *question bank*, while you want to refer it to the *attached file*. By adding *which we*, you indicate that you (as a group, you could also use **I** if you did it by yourself), collated the information in the file.

You could also rephrase it altogether, I think this might be even clearer, the sentence at the start of my answer might be read as *the question bank which we collated*.

> Please see **the** attached file **which we**, during our meetings, collated for our Question bank.

You could also say this, if the question bank was the only subject of your meetings (the emphasis is now less on the files being for your question bank). In this case, it might also be more natural to swap our for the:

> Please see **the** attached file **which we** collated during (our / the) meetings for our Question bank.

Answer (score 0):

**collate** means to collect and combine data, information, or texts.  See https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/collate

The word occurs, as the examples suggest, in articles or papers describing a research process.  It is puzzling to me that you speak of collating occurring in meetings.  People meet to talk and interact; they don't meet to put together data or sort cards or put information in order, although perhaps they did.

Collating is what a copier does when it puts copies in order. At least that's the most common use today in American English, other than in research reports and in the description of computer programs that sort data.

My guess is that in these meetings, people discussed which questions to include in the Question bank, possibly providing lists of questions that were later assembled in a file (document); the document is now being passed out to people who attend these meetings.

So my guess is that "collate" is not the word you want.